# extracting part of an image outlined with a red box with OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, character, detection

I have the following image [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j82CY.gif)

---

I need to recognize the Character within it. To do this i want to produce a mask to remove everything but the red box.

What is the best method i could use to do this?

Currently I use a hsv filter to produce a mask, and use the mask to crop the image to just the red square.

```
cvtColor(src, HSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
inRange(HSV, Scalar(H_MIN, S_MIN, V_MIN), Scalar(H_MAX, S_MAX, V_MAX), HSVmask);
src.copyTo(src2, HSVmask);
```

This produces a poor mask as it has the T itself excluded depending on how i view the image, i need a more robust approach.

-I was wondering if there is a way to make a box around the significant white region and use the box as my mask instead, however i'm not sure on how to implement that on opencv.

With the mask i apply a canny edge detection, then i find the contours and fill the contours.

My results 
[Contour Output and Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9hhn.png)

The result i get isn't robust enough, i ideally need to be able to detect a large sign on a grass field from an aerial video feed, so it needs to work with the red square with different sizes.

Is there any way in which i can improve this process in general?

The character recognition method hasn't been decided yet.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like: Mat1b mask; inRange (image, Scalar(255,0,0), Scalar(255,0,0), mask);

Answer (score 0):

**If you just want to recognize the character**

1. Convert image to gray scale.
2. Since the character is white and rest of image is colored, the character in the gray image will still be white. So take a threshold and suppress all non white pixels.
3. Run your classifier to recognize the character.

**If you want to extract the red box**

1. Locate the red pixels, then crop image.